# How to get sum of values by grouping using laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

This is my MySQL table.
[image]

I want to group rows by `vehicle_id` and get total cost for each `vehicle_id`. For ex:- `vehicle_id`=20 cost should be like 1300+2600=3900. and should get the distinct row for each `vehicle_id` and need a new column for each vehicle_id as `total_cost`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group with raw query:

`Table::groupBy('vehicle_id')
   ->selectRaw('sum(cost) as sum, vehicle_id')
   ->pluck('sum','vehicle_id');`

Also sql query with tested resulted is:

```
SELECT SUM(cost) as total, vehicle_id FROM `test` GROUP BY(vehicle_id)
```